# How to group query result by a specific field in MongoDB without mutating the object?

Tags: mongodb

I have a sample collection containing users and their departments

```
db.user.insertMany([
   {
      "department":"IT",
      "firstName":{
         "en":"Frodo",
         "ru":"Фродо"
      },
      "lastName":{
         "en":"Baggins",
         "ru":"Беггинс"
      }
   },
   {
      "department":"IT",
      "firstName":{
         "en":"Bilbo",
         "ru":"Билбо"
      },
      "lastName":{
         "en":"Baggins",
         "ru":"Беггинс"
      }
   },
   {
      "department":"Marketing",
      "firstName":{
         "en":"Merry",
         "ru":"Мери"
      },
      "lastName":{
         "en":"Brandybuck",
         "ru":"Брендибак"
      }
   },
   {
      "department":"Marketing",
      "firstName":{
         "en":"Pippin",
         "ru":"Пипин"
      },
      "lastName":{
         "en":"Took",
         "ru":"Тук"
      }
   }
])
```

Now what I want to do, is to query them grouped by the department, and apply localization.
So the desired output is

```
{
   "IT":[
      {
         "_id":"5e808532ed036001cb7fe366",
         "firstName":"Frodo",
         "lastName":"Baggins"
      },
      {
         "_id":"5e808532ed036001cb7fe367",
         "firstName":"Bilbo",
         "lastName":"Baggins"
      }
   ],
   "Marketing":[
      {
         "_id":"5e808532ed036001cb7fe368",
         "firstName":"Merry",
         "lastName":"Brandybuck"
      },
      {
         "_id":"5e808532ed036001cb7fe369",
         "firstName":"Pippin",
         "lastName":"Took"
      }
   ]
}
```

I have the following query which applies localization

```
db.user.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            _id: '$_id',
            firstName: '$firstName.en',
            lastName: '$lastName.en'
        }
    }
]).pretty()
```

I looked through the `$group` documentation, but it seems to require an aggregate function, which is not what I need. How should I group the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use $group.

```
 db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$department",
      data: {
        $push: {
          _id: "$_id",
          firstName: "$firstName",
          lastName: "$lastName"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      data: {
        $push: {
          k: "$_id",
          v: "$data"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $arrayToObject: "$data"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KXpouJ6Ensr)

Comment: Thanks. Didn't know about the `$push` and `$arrayToObject` operators.

Comment: Yes they are amazing.